# MySQL - How to calculate current time and a time stored in a fied?

Tags: mysql, time

What is the function that would return, in minutes, the current time and another time in a field?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean.

Comment: the current time and another time??? don't understand the question.... `SELECT NOW()` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select mytable.mytimecolumn, now() from mytable
```

if you want the difference in minutes,

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,now(),mytable.mytimecolumn) from mytable
```